Where do Hong Kong villages - Lei Yue Mun or Sam Shing - get their seafood from?
I want to eat seafood Hong Kong style in Lei Yue Mun or Sam Shing.
But seafood at Lei Yue Mun and Sam Shing is a marketing gimmick, many expats warn me. These "fishermen" show off their "local catch" on "fishing boats". But these "fishermen" never caught this "local" seafood", never caught anywhere near Lei Yue Mun or Sam Shing! These "fishermen" import the seafood from other Asian countries like Vietnam, for false advertising and food fraud.
Who's telling the truth? expats? Or these local fishermen?
Where's the seafood at Lei Yue Mun and Sam Shing from? Village waters? Mainland China? Or far away?

"Who's telling the truth? expats? Or these local fishermen"  I do rather wonder why "expats" in all its specific-yet-vague glory would be a source of any value on this, but skipping that... you're asking about entire districts with large numbers of independent traders. Have you considered there may be both genuine locally-caught seafood and people flogging cheap stuff at a markup?

Short answer: The seafood sold in Sam Sing and Lei Yue Mun seafood markets is extremely unlikely from "village waters". More generally, only a small portion of seafood sold in Hong Kong is captured/cultured within Hong Kong waters. They are more likely caught in the South China Sea or imported elsewhere.

According to the Agriculture, Fisheries and Conservation Department (AFCD) of the Hong Kong SAR Government, roughly 15% of fish consumed in Hong Kong were produced locally in 2023, either captured or cultured.
Many Hong Kong-domiciled fishing vessels operate outside Hong Kong waters (which spans a mere 1651 sq. km). According to AFCD:

Fishing activities in the waters of Hong Kong are mainly conducted by sampans using multiple fishing gears as well as other smaller non-trawler vessels (such as gill netters, long liners, purse seiners, etc.). On the other hand, trawlers and other larger non-trawlers are generally operating in the adjacent waters of the South China Sea.

There are very few resources describing specific market dynamics. That said, fishing vessels operating within Hong Kong waters mainly obtain their yield in the more remote areas south of Lantau Island, east of Sai Kung, and around Cheung Chau and Lamma Island. I have reproduced Figure 3.1 of the linked report with annotations of the locations mentioned:

As we can see, it is extremely unlikely that any commercial-level yield is caught locally (here construed as within/next to the harbour) in Lei Yue Mun or Sam Sing seafood markets. This makes sense, as both places are less a standalone village but more part of a large urban area -- Sam Sing is within the Tuen Mun New Town (pop. ~500k), and Lei Yue Mun is at the far east end of Kowloon (pop. ~3m on both sides of Victoria Harbour).

While truly local (here construed as within Hong Kong waters) seafood is getting rare, which stems from/leads to a wide range of topics related to sustainable fishing, it doesn't mean they are never sold in the said seafood markets or direct by the fishermen. One may consider confirming the origin of the fish by asking

啲魚邊度嚟㗎 (di yu bin dou lai ga)?
Where do these fish come from?

or

有無本地魚賣 (yau mou boon dei yu maai)?
Are there any local fish for sale?

Similar to other places, there will always be unscrupulous merchants who lie to make some sales. Fortunately, the problem is more ambiguous labelling or lack of information rather than people giving false statements.
